# Jmeter server-agent - what are the consequences (-ve effects) ?is it installing anything on the server?

Tags: jmeter

Jmeter server-agent - if we run it on the server (Windows server 2008, 2012) where java is not present, what are the consequences (-ve effects) ? when we run that agent on server side, what is does actually? is it installing anything on the server? 
Considering mission-critical application server, is there any possibility that it will disturb other operations on the server? 
I have read that we can run server-agent even if java is not present on the server (by keeping JRE folder on the server)

Answer (score 1):

As per the [documentation](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMonAgent/):

> The agent is written in Java, so **you will need JRE 1.4+ to run it**

so you will definitely need JRE.

With regards to impact, it depends on 3 factors:

1. Java Heap size allocated to the ServerAgent process. It relies on Java default initial and maximum heap values, you can check them using following command:

   ```
   java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | findstr HeapSize
   ```

   If needed you can control JVM heap allocation using `-Xms` and `Xmx` parameters
2. How many metrics are being monitored
3. How often you are querying the ServerAgent (controllable via `--interval` option on ServerAgent side or `jmeterPlugin.perfmon.interval` JMeter Property)

See [How to Monitor Your Server Health & Performance During a JMeter Load Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test) article for more information on installation, configuration and usage of the PerfMon Plugin.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have still one query - how it is advisable to put on the windows server 2008/2012? will it affect existing working of the application server? we can install anything on the server. we have to try if it will work by putting JRE folder as it is written in documentation.

Comment: If you have Java already installed - it will work. If you don't have Java - you will have to either install it or to copy existing JRE or JDK installation from another machine. It will not interfere with other applications, in regards to resource consumption by the agent itself - its totally up to you